# Image wont appear in the background

Tags: html, css, web

I am trying to show `test.png` in the background, but it doesn't show up.

Below is what I tried:

HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="menubalkje"></div>
    <div class="menu"></div>
    <div class="content">
        test
    </div>
    <img class="bgafb" src="images/test.png">
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    padding:0px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.menubalkje{
    background-color:#b32b00;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    width:1200px;
    height:25px;
}

.menu{
    background-color:E53700;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    width:1200px;
    height:75px;
}

.content{
     background-color:#ff3e01;
     width:1200px;
     height:100%;
     margin-left:auto;
     margin-right:auto;
}

.bgafb{
    position:fixed;
    left:-270px;
    -moz-transform: scaleX(-1);
    -o-transform: scaleX(-1);
    -webkit-transform: scaleX(-1);
    transform: scaleX(-1);
    filter: FlipH;
    -ms-filter: "FlipH";
}
```

The `img` element with id `bgafb` needs to show the background image, but doesn't.

Comment: Try to using my updated answer

Answer (score 1):

Add `background` property with comma separated values in your CSS like:

```
  #divId {
    background:url(images/image1.png) repeat-x, url(images/image2.png) repeat;
}
```

Hope This Help.

Got Help from **[HERE](http://blog.thelibzter.com/css-tricks-use-two-background-images-for-one-div/)**:

Comment: Not in the body. In a DIV to get it on the background because i need 2 images in the background on different places.

Answer (score 1):

The image shows for me (I tried with a http url, as I don't have your database)

http://jsfiddle.net/z8dw4Lfz/

```
  <img class="bgafb" src="http://img0.chromatic.io/d8fb8ca6-3b46-d763-9dbf-fd8388402d1d/small.jpg">
```

Comment: Yeah. I know that xD but i need it to the background with 2 images. 2 differend images on both sides.

Comment: He want to add background image to body and you are suggesting img tag

Comment: So if I understood well you want an image to the left and one to the right on a background right?                                             .bgafb{
background:url(http://img0.chromatic.io/d8fb8ca6-3b46-d763-9dbf-fd8388402d1d/small.jpg) no-repeat left, url(http://img0.chromatic.io/f30bed2b-1888-6f88-20c4-d3870a2a9d62/small.jpg) no-repeat right;
 width:1900px;
    height:800px;
-moz-transform: scaleX(-1);
-o-transform: scaleX(-1);
-webkit-transform: scaleX(-1);
transform: scaleX(-1);
filter: FlipH;
-ms-filter: "FlipH";
 }

Answer (score 1):

probabily you are giving left:-270px; in  .bgafb class which is disapearing the image from the screen. if you will set it to left:0px; then image will show in body

Comment: Its a wide image like 600 width. so it wont disapear :P

Answer (score -1):

If you want to use something as a background image, put it in the body of your CSS.

```
body {
background-image: url('path_to_image');
}
```